# 404 after recommending deletion in "Low Quality Posts" queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

This has happened to me 4 times in the past hour, on two different machines. Both on normal posts and in what appear to be clearly audits.

When going through the "Low Quality Posts" queue, if I click 'Recommend Deletion' , I get a 404.

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

If I click 'looks good' it works fine, although the only way I could prove it was by intentionally failing an audit:
[image]

Comment: Just tried a LQ review - got a 404. Never got that before. Triggered by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15823606/23897), which isn't (apparently) an audit.

Comment: I was JUST coming to report this..

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta / Seth glad it's not just me...

Comment: I just wanted to add, this has happened again on another review item, so it wasn't just one specific item.

Comment: @Seth for me at least it happens on **every** review item in the "Low Quality Posts" queue. (at leasts the ones I click "Recommend Deletion" for)

Comment: This is still a problem, happened to me several times in the last 30 minutes. The items do not seem to get out of the queue as I have had at least 2 of them multiple times.

Comment: it's probably my fault will take a look in a couple hours.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Not sure if that helps, but although I have the same problem multiple times on the same post, after 3-4 times they don't seem to pop-up any more. Maybe not everyone has the problem and/or moderators are able to remove these from the queues

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had inadvertedly removed a `return false;` from a JavaScript continuation in a previous unrelated patch… 
I've fixed it now.

It will be rolled out in the next deployment.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7115/page-not-found-error-after-reviewing-an-answer looks like the same issue, should also be status-completed

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept as soon as I confirm it's working again.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - No need to confirm. If SE Employee mark the question as `Status-Completed` then it will be implemented/fixed from the next build. :)

Comment: Should be out now.

Comment: Tested it on both audits and normal posts - works fine :)